# ¿Como relacionar en SQLSERVER dos columnas de una misma tabla para crear una tercera columna?

Tags: sql-server

Mi pregunta es si en sqlserver se puede crear una columna relacionando dos columnas de la misma tabla, supongamos que tengo una tabla de ventas con las siguientes columnas.

Articulo   Precio   cantidad      total(precio*cantidad)

Para la tabla total es el resultado de multiplicar precio*cantidad
¿Se pueden relacionar estas dos columnas(precio y cantidad) para crear una tercera columna.

si es si.¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?.

Gracias

Comment: También puedes crearte un trigger en tu tabla *Ventas* para que apenas insertes un dato el trigger realice una operación y pueda hacer el cálculo y actualizar ese campo, es un poco más complejo pero la ventaja que tienes al usar triggers es que puedes hacer muchas más operaciones en segundo plano apenas insertes un dato. El uso de triggers en SQL Server es una gran ventaja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al crear la tabla puedes hacerlo:

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla
    (
    Precio int,
    Cantidad int,
    Total AS Precio * Cantidad
    )
```

Si ya tienes la tabla creada puedes editar (diseñar en SSMS) la consulta y poner la fórmula (Precio * Cantidad) en "Especificación de columna calculada" dentro de las propiedades del campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]